# Qt cleanup on exit?

Tags: qt, signals, exit

I have an application for which a cleanup code should be run regardless of the way how the process ended. For example, if the program is being closed by the OS due to a restart, the cleanup code should be executed. Or if CTRL+C is pressed, the cleanup code should be executed.

I've found the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit` signal.

The docs for the signal state:

> This signal is emitted when the application is about to quit the main event loop, e.g. when the event loop level drops to zero. This
>   may happen either after a call to quit() from inside the application
>   or when the users shuts down the entire desktop session.
>
> The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some
>   last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this
>   state.

However after testing, I've noticed that the signal isn't emitted when CTRL-C is pressed. It also isn't emitted when terminated by `kill`.

On what 'exit' events is the signal emitted?

*My current opinion is that `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit` is useless for handling outside signals and that it is used for 'exiting from inside an app' kind of events (a user clicks the X button to close the window), but won't help you if you want to make sure a certain event is executed even on a segmentation fault or the process being externally killed.*

Comment: What kind of cleanup do you mean? When a process is terminated, all memory it allocates is released, so unless you use shared memory or some other inter-process communication, you shouldn't really have to do anything. And besides, how do you expect your cleanup code to run if the PC gets restarted? It is simply not possible.

Comment: Have you tried [qAddPostRoutine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#qAddPostRoutine)?

Comment: @ddriver For example. The app sets iptables, and should return them to the original state if something happens. It also communicates with some external systems that will go on forever if the app doesn't send them the ending messages.

Comment: As stated from @ddriver you should rethink your approach since some (absolutely not so) extreme cases could happen. Having said that, it could be of general interest this [wiki article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

Comment: @Alan - in this case you should also install a script that runs on OS boot just in case there was a forced restart, so your cleanup can run if your terminate handler doesn't get the chance, if normal cleanup succeeds the autorun script is removed.

Comment: Have tried `closeEvent` ?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Read the link you gave me. Sure looks like a hack :). I took a different approach. I've made the pointers to the object that provide me with the required control functions global and am now accessing them in the signal handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (had the same problem a while back and found it to work quite well):

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Good sample code + all system signals:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html